# QueryOver Only <one to many> property

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, queryover

I'm working with NHibernate and QueryOver. I have an aggregate root for my aggregate named **Parent** and two kinds of child entity. I have **Child** entities that are parts of my aggregate, and **QUChild** entities that are not parts of my aggregate, and are just used for JOIN clause in QueryOver.

How to distinguish between two child entities in mapping file?

```
<class name="Parent" table="Parent" schema="dbo">
      <bag name="Childs" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" />
        <key>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Child" />
      </bag>
      <bag name="QUChilds"  /> <!-- which attribute must be set to do nothing? -->
        <key>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="QUChild" />
      </bag>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just do nothing with it. NHibernate will not eager load, nor lazy-load it if you do not access it from your loaded parent entities.

And default cascade is `none`, so just leave it as you have mapped it. (But I would add `inverse="true"` just in case code changes lead to add some children in that collection too, later on.)